# Two web.config in one root directory?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is it possible to put two `web.config` by different projects in the same root directory?

In the first project I have my website and in the second one, I have A restful web service.

Comment: is it possible to put two different files with the same name into the same folder?

Comment: perfect answer for perfect Question @lashane

Comment: why do you want to do that? You can put the same/shared config into root web.config of the site, and write/overwrite the app specific config into app level web.config. Or wrap the config with <location> in the root web.config.